# Reader-writer concurrency

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, concurrency, pthreads

I am trying to achieve the following scenario. In case of only readers in the system, don't take the mutex. I have written the following implementation.

```
LockReader()
{
  flag = 0;
  atomic increment cntReader;
  if(atomic check cntWriter > 0)
  {
    while(noLock != 0);
    flag = 1;
    mutexLock(var);
  }
  else
  {
    atomic increment noLock;
  }

  //CS

  if(flag == 1)
    mutexUnlock(var);
  else
    atomic decrement noLock;

  atomic decrement cntReader;
}

LockWriter()
{
  atomic increment cntWriter;
  if(atomic check cntReader > 0)
  {
    while(noLock != 0);
  }

  mutexLock(var);

  mutexUnlock(var);
  atomic decrement cntWriter;

}
```

But this code has the issue that, if there is a reader and it gets context switch after evaluating line 3 of LockShared(`if(cntWriter > 1)`) and a writer comes, then it can get the mutexLock, since noLock  is not incremented yet. And after the mutexLock, if writer is context switched, the reader will also be allowed. We have let both reader and writer together.

How do I avoid this scenario?

EDIT 1:
I have changed LockReader() this way:

```
LockReader()
{
  flag = 0;
  atomic increment cntReader;
  atomic increment noLock;
  if(atomic check cntWriter > 0)
  {
    atomic decrement noLock;
    while(noLock != 0);
    flag = 1;
    mutexLock(var);
  }

  //CS

  if(flag == 1)
    mutexUnlock(var);
  else
    atomic decrement noLock;

  atomic decrement cntReader;
}
```

I think this should fix the issue I mentioned. But are there any other reader-writer concurrency problems possible?

EDIT 2: Added unlock code as well.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  An uncontended lock should not be expensive to acquire.  Seems like erroneous optimization.

Comment: For the completeness, could you please provide the corresponding unlock functions?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I am trying to improve the performance. Taking exclusive mutex lock even for readers are bringing down the performance badly.

Comment: @AndriyBerestovskyy Added.

Answer (score 0):

If it is all about the performance, you should not use mutex at all. Instead use just one counter and busy waiting, i.e.:

```
volatile int rw_lock;

LockReader() {
    int l, success = 0;

    while (success == 0) {
        l = rw_lock;
        if (l < 0) {
            // wait for a writer
            continue;
        }
        // atomically increment rw_lock
        success == cmpset(rw_lock, l, l + 1);
    }
}

LockWriter() {
    int l, success = 0;

    while (success == 0) {
        l = rw_lock;
        if (l != 0) {
            // wait for readers
            continue;
        }
        // atomically set rw_lock to -1
        success = cmpset(rw_lock, 0, -1);
    }
}

UnlockReader() {
    atomic_dec(rw_lock);
}

UnlockWriter() {
    atomic_inc(rw_lock);
}
```

Those type of locks are called reader-writer locks. You can find more info at Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock

EDIT:
Write-preferring version:

```
volatile int rw_lock;
volatile int w_req;

LockReader() {
    int l, success = 0;

    while (success == 0) {
        while (w_req) {
            // wait due to write preference
        }
        l = rw_lock;
        if (l < 0) {
            // wait for a writer
            continue;
        }
        // atomically increment rw_lock
        success == cmpset(rw_lock, l, l + 1);
    }
}

LockWriter() {
    int l, success = 0;

    w_req = 1; // request a write, i.e. block new reads
    while (success == 0) {
        l = rw_lock;
        if (l != 0) {
            // wait for readers
            continue;
        }
        // atomically set rw_lock to -1
        success = cmpset(rw_lock, 0, -1);
    }
    w_req = 0; // allow new reads
}

UnlockReader() {
    atomic_dec(rw_lock);
}

UnlockWriter() {
    atomic_inc(rw_lock);
}
```

Comment: I am handicapped from not being able to use `__sync_val_compare_and_swap` as the gcc supported by the product is 4.3.4

Comment: Also, the code could lead to writer starvation? Is my observation right?

Comment: @user2761431 1. You need __sync_bool_compare_and_swap and it should be available in gcc 4.3.4    2. Please refer the Wikipedia link, there are Write-preferring RW locks.